# List of values to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with some string values:

```
['red', 'blue']
```

And I want to use those strings as values in single, constant keyed dictionaries. So the output would be:

```
[{'color': 'red'}, {'color': 'blue'}]
```

Comment: Have you tried to write any code for this? Do you know about list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a list to a list of dictionaries like this:

```
colors = ["red", "blue"]
colors = [{'color': c} for c in colors]
>>> [{'color': 'red'}, {'color': 'blue'}]
```

This will create a list of dictionaries by iterating through the list.

Below is exactly the same code, but written in a way most beginners can understand it better:

```
colors = ["red", "blue"] # get a list of colors
new_colors = [] # create empty list to store final result
for c in colors: # go over each color in colorsarray
    new_colors.append({'color': c}) # append a dictionary to the new_colors array
>>> [{'color': 'red'}, {'color': 'blue'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, and pythonic, way would be a 'comprehension' as follows:

```
colors = ["red", "blue"]
print(colors)
color_dict = [{"color": x} for x in colors]
print(color_dict)
```

```
['red', 'blue']
[{'color': 'red'}, {'color': 'blue'}]
```

The comprehension creates a new structure from a list or other iterable. In this case, it's constructing a list comprising `{"color": x}` for every `x` element in the list.